# Prevent Application from running inside the wrong folder

Tags: c#, uri, directory, environment

I have a (rather huge) application which is depending on some resources residing in the same folder as the application (e.g. settings files, unmanaged libraries etc.).
I also have registered a URI-protocol for this application, so that every URI-call starting with `xyz://...` will launch my application with the respective parameters.

The problem is, that if you use the URI-call, the application will run from the `%windir%/system32`-folder, or the `../ProgramFiles/Chrome/...`-folder (when the URI is called from my webbrowser). It will not run my application from the folder, which it resides in.

*(you can probably see my problem already...)*

If my app runs from the sys32-folder it will (naturally) not have access to the local libraries, which some of my P/Invoke functions need.

---

My question is: how can I run my application from the correct folder or prevent it being run from a folder like sys32?

---

*And no - I do not like following idea:*

```
if (Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToLower() != "/my/home/dir") {
    MessageBox.Show("You have no power over here!");

    Exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Directory.SetCurrentDirectory("c:\path your exe resides in")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028761/prevent-application-from-running-inside-the-wrong-folder?noredirect=1#comment55813476_34028761) written by [@MutantNinjaCodeMonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/92196/mutantninjacodemonkey) helped me out in the end:

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(@"c:\path\to\app");
```

"resets" the working directory to the desired path. In my specific case I used:

```
FileInfo nfo = new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(nfo.Directory.FullName);
```